# Facebook permission dialogue not showing in iOS app

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.x

In latest Facebook SDK, permission pop up not appearing.
loginbehavvior is set as .native.
Bundle id is added in app settings.
If anybody knows about this, please help.